# Como puedo el promedio con un numero dado de materias usando la sentencia while o for?

Tags: c, bucle-for, while

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación entre las actividades que me dejaron necesito sacar el **promedio de un alumno** pero el numero de materias la proporciona el usuario, puedo usar la sentencia while o for, el código debe estar escrito en lenguaje c.

Esto es lo poco que llevo del código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    int main(){

    int mate, suma, i, cal, prom;

    printf("Cuantas materias son? ");
    scanf ("%d", &i);

    for(mate=0; mate>=i; mate++){

        printf("Cual es la calificacion? ");
        scanf("%d", &cal);
        suma=cal+cal;
    }
    prom=suma/i;

    if(prom>=5 && prom<=10){
        printf("Aprobaste");
        printf("n\ Tu promedio es de &d", prom);
    }
    else{
        printf("Reprobaste");
        printf("n\ Tu promedio es de &d", prom);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agrega lo que lleves por favor, checa [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código tiene varias fallas:

**-1.** La variable `suma` debe ser inicializada a `0`, de lo contrario, no podrás obtener el total de calificaciones.

**-2.** La condición del bucle for no tiene sentido: `mate>=i`. Es decir, si la cantidad de materias es `10` y la variable `mate` vale `0`, nunca se cumplirá la condición, **siempre** dará como resultado un `false`. Así que la restricción correcta debería ser: `mate < i`.

**-3.** Esta expresión `suma=cal+cal` no estará sumando en cada iteración la calificación del estudiante, por lo tanto, debe ser cambiada a: `suma = suma + cal`.

**-4.** Si quieres hacer un salto de línea en la función `printf`, no deberías usar `n\` sino `\n`.

**-5.** Para poder imprimir el promedio en pantalla no debes usar esto `&d`, sino `%d`.

El código completo con las correcciones quedaría de esta forma:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{

   int mate, suma = 0, i, cal, prom;

   printf("Cuantas materias son? ");
   scanf ("%d", &i);

   for(mate=0; mate < i; mate++){

      printf("Cual es la calificacion? ");
      scanf("%d", &cal);
      suma= suma + cal;
   }
   prom=suma/i;

   if(prom>=5 && prom<=10){
      printf("Aprobaste");
      printf("\n Tu promedio es de %d", prom);
   }
   else{
      printf("Reprobaste");
      printf("\n Tu promedio es de %d", prom);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**Recomendación:** En vez de usar la variable `i` como el total de materias, hubieras usado como nombre `total_mate` (el nombre es más descriptivo). El identificador `i` se suele usar para contar las iteraciones que hace un bucle.

En vez de imprimir el promedio tanto en la condicional como en el caso contrario, podemos simplemente hacer esto:

```c
if(prom>=5 && prom<=10)
    printf("Aprobaste");
  else
    printf("Reprobaste");
printf("\n Tu promedio es de %d", prom);
```

Y si quieres el código más reducido, puedes optar en usar el operador ternario de esta manera:

```c
printf("%s\nTu promedio es de %d", (prom>=5 && prom<=10) ? ("Aprobaste") : ("Reprobaste"), prom);
```

**Nota:** El operador ternario es simplemente la abreviación de un `if-else`, así que no es nada del otro mundo.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int mate, suma = 0, i, cal, prom;

    printf("Cuantas materias son? ");
    scanf ("%d",&i);

    for(mate = 0; mate < i; mate++){
        printf("Cual es la calificacion? ");
        scanf("%d",&cal);
        suma = suma+cal;
    }

    prom = suma/i;

    if(prom >= 5 && prom <= 10){
        printf("Aprobaste");
        printf("\n Tu promedio es de %d", prom);
    }else{
        printf("Reprobaste");
        printf("\n Tu promedio es de %d", prom);
    }

    return 0;
}
```